# Android Studio Changelist Directory

Tags: git, android-studio

I apologize if this has been asked anywhere before, but I certainly could not find the answer online.

Does anybody know what directory Android Studio (version 1.5.1) saves git changelists too? I Copied a project I need to work on over Spring Break to a USB drive, but the changelists don't show up. I SSH'ed into my home computer, but couldn't seem to find anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio keep files in both `.idea` & `.git` folder.

You should copy all the project folder and then import it to your new studio

Comment: I had done this, but I guess my hidden directories didn't copy to my laptop, but it all works now, thanks!

Comment: Cool. glad to help. and yep hidden folder sometimes are hidden :-)